# What is the effect of multiple Register file ports of a CPU?

Tags: computer-architecture

Register file ports are a means to get data in and out of registers in a CPU. The concept of having multiple ports is not too clear to me.

QUESTION

Assuming you have 2 read ports, does it mean different stages of a CPU pipeline can simultaneously read from the register file (same / different registers)?

Comment: Back way up.  If you only have one port, you can only write or read one register at a time.  Think about the sequence of events then needed to execute a typical instruction...

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, having two read ports doesn't *only* have one good reason. For example, a CPU without pipelining might read from two registers at the same time, perform any one of several classes of ALU operations, and perform a register write also in the same cycle. So here, there are two read ports and one write port to the register file. But there is ***no*** pipeline. In cases where there ***is*** a pipeline, there may be other reasons for wanting two read ports. And they would be ***different*** reasons. Not the same. So there isn't one answer to your question.